Bamboo appears to be not fetching tags from Bitbucket
We have a checkout task in our bamboo-specs YAML file thus:
- checkout:
  force-clean-build: "false"
  description: Checkout default repository

As part of our build processes, we want to run release analysis on projects and this analysis needs to know, among other things, all tags currently set in the repo along with their git hashes. The script uses git tag to get all tags and then, for each, a git rev-list -n 1 <tag> to get the hash.
However, while the script works fine in my local repo, it fails on Bamboo because it appears that the tags do not exist in its checked-out repo. The tags definitely exist in BitBucket (I've pushed them upstream). For example, the Bamboo web interface shows that 1.0.0rc1 exists but the analysis scripts running on Bamboo do not find it.
My guess is that the Bamboo checkout task is doing some type of "light-weight" clone. I know that previous shops I've worked in do similar things, such as only doing a shallow clone, or only getting objects that affect the branch being checked out as part of the clone.
That's understandable as there's little point getting the entire repo history if you're only going to build a single hash).
Searching for a solution has not turned up anything. There a question related to Jenkins which is similar but, of course, that's not Bamboo.
The documentation on the checkout task shows no options that would be useful (such as "Get the damn tags as well [X]`) so there's no joy there :-)
So I'm wondering if there's a way to either:

tell checkout (in the bamboo-specs YAML file) that I need it to fetch all tags; or
figure out how to run a task after checkout that runs git fetch --tags (assuming I can ensure I run it from within the Bamboo repo).

The latter possibility would probably be the best since I may need other things later on (such as the entire repo history, not just the tags).

Extra information, the output from the Bamboo log when attempting a git tag is (formatted for readability):
build 18-Apr-2024 08:02:40 <<< ERROR[0bbdd4cc]: error: object directory
      /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/_git-repositories-cache/
      9c8324fc55f93ea4c7a0730ef5791ddc872de550/.git/objects
   does not exist; check .git/objects/info/alternates

With the git rev-list:
build 18-Apr-2024 08:02:40 <<< ERROR[0bbdd4cc ]: error: refs/tags/1.0.0rc1
   does not point to a valid object!

So I'm wondering if the tags do exist but it's just that the objects they point to aren't there (because of the afore-mentioned shallow clone possibility?). If so, maybe there's a way to get the tag-to-git-hash mapping without the backing objects existing.

This solution worked for me: Go to the "General" -> "Advanced options" of the linked repository and uncheck the "Enable repository caching on agents" option.
